# Где найти правило, с прописной или со строчной писать названия падежей в русском языке?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В школах на самом деле учат писать с прописной?

> Откуда вы знаете, что названия падежей пишутся с маленькой буквы? где
>   про это прочитать? и почему тогда в школах преподают с большой? откуда
>   "ноги" растут???

Из методички:

> Названия падежей обозначаются с большой буквы (И.п.).

Действительно, а при сокращении до начальных букв как верно?

Comment: Вы, видимо, опять неверно поняли. У Вас в цитате: названия ***обозначаются***. Да, когда идет сокращение, то заглавная нагляднее. Но это актуально только в табличке, где каждый падеж - новая строка. В тексте детям сокращать не положено.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...как верно?

Верно (к примеру, для именительного падежа) и ***И. п.***, и ***и. п.***, и ***им. п.*** (вместо ***п.*** возможно ***пад.***) — именно такие сокращения зафиксированы в *"Русском орфографическом словаре" (4-е изд.; М., 2012).*

Наиболее информативны, на мой взгляд, первый и третий варианты.

[**В учебнике *Литневской***](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i2) использован первый вариант:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В книге *Бабайцевой "Анализ слова и предложения" (М., 2014)* — третий: ***им. п.***

Нельзя не отметить, что в лингвистической литературе обозначение названий падежей **начальными прописными буквами** широко распространено.

Вот как, к примеру, выглядит отрывок из учебника для пединститутов под ред. Максимова ("Русский язык", ч. 2, М., 1989):

> *Одушевленность / неодушевленность проявляется грамматически, в формах В. падежа существительных: у одушевленных существительных формы В.
>   падежа множ. числа (всех типов склонения) совпадают с формами Р.
>   падежа; у существительных же   неодушевленных — с формами И. падежа.*

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого правила. И нет причины писать с прописной буквы (таков ответ с Грамота.ру). И ни в одном словаре, включая Розенталя "Прописная или строчная?", такого написания нет. Доказывать надо не общее употребление слова, а исключение.

Comment: Для меня очевидно, что причины нет (писать с прописной), но на вопрос меня навело частое употребление прописной школьниками. Сюда я попала из *Как правильно определить падеж - Родительный или Винительный?

"Организация сообщает о принятии к исполнению Постановлени (е) или Постановлени (я)? " Какое должно быть окончание у слова в единственном числе и как определить правильно падеж - Родительный или Винительный?* Думала, есть какое-то компетентное разъяснение, почему эта ошибка так распространена.

Answer (score 0):

С заглавной пишут только в табличках: И., Р. и т. д. 
А на основании чего делается утверждение, что в школах учат иному?

Могу предположить только влияние общей грамматики или европейских языков, где такие вещи пишут обычно с заглавной.