# Вопрос Римме Михайловой

Tags: прописная-строчная

Почему Вы считаете, что правильно наименования падежей при сокращении писать с большой буквы?

Comment: Да я спросил в комментариях два раза, а Римма не ответила. Что ж ещё делать, shampar?

Comment: В чат уходить и обращаться на Вы.

Comment: Предлагаю перейти в чат: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/.

Comment: Ну хорошо, переправил на "Вы", хотя другое не отбавляет моего уважения, а что значит в чат уходить?

Comment: @Aer: дело в том, что Римма мне не ответила даже когда я повторил вопрос, поэтому надеялся привлечь её внимание так. В чат она уж точно не зайдёт.

Comment: @Aer: я так и не понял, что мне делать в этой ситуации.

Comment: Выше я дал ссылку на чат, где можно задать персональные вопросы. Уверен, что также можно задать ваш вопрос в комментариях под сообщениями Риммы Михайловой. «Задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы не предназначена для личных вопросов.

Comment: @Aer: спасибо. Под комментариями я как раз два раза уже спросил, а в чат, думаю, она не зайдёт.

Comment: @Артём Луговой,если вас интересует, как писать названия падежей, этот вопрос на сайте обсуждался.

Comment: @Серж: да? А можете ссылочку дать?

Comment: @Артём Луговой, вот, пожалуйста. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/421051/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: Спасибо большое, Серж!