# Как правильно: Тв. п. или тв. п.?

Tags: прописная-строчная, сокращения

Я уже много времени вижу, что аббревиатуры падежей пишут с большой буквы.
Можете сказать почему? Может быть, это вообще так отнюдь не правильно?
Другими словами, как правильно в таких примерах?

1.1. Напишите слово *лист* с префиксом *пол-* в Р. п.
1.2. Напишите слово *лист* с префиксом *пол-* в р. п.
2.1. Русские Тв. и Им. падежи – это нечто.
2.2. Русские тв. и им. падежи – это нечто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как правильно: Тв. п. или тв. п.?

**Оба варианта правильны.**

«Русским орфографическим словарём» под ред. Лопатина зафиксированы такие общепринятые графические сокращения:

> **И., и., им.** именительный падеж
>
> **Р., р., род.** родительный падеж
>
> **Д., д., дат.** дательный падеж
>
> **В., в., вин.** винительный падеж
>
> **Д., д., дат.** дательный падеж
>
> **Т., т., тв.** и **твор.** творительный падеж
>
> **П., п., предл.** предложный падеж
>
> **п.** и **пад.** падеж

Answer (score 4):

К первому ответу (правильному — о записи сокращений вообще) добавлю ссылку на подобный вопрос на нашем сайте:
[Где найти правило, с прописной или со строчной писать названия падежей в русском языке?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/421051/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Добавлю еще информацию "Грамоты" о том, что сами *названия* падежей в тексте, конечно же, пишутся со строчной буквы ([Вопрос № 299226](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9&start=150)).

А сверх того добавлю ссылку собственно на [«Русский орфографический словарь»](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html) под редакцией В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой (2013).
Кроме оформления сокращений падежей (***п.*** и ***пад.*** — падеж; ***тв.***, ***твор.***, ***Т.***, ***т.*** — творительный падеж), здесь можно ознакомиться и с другими распространенными сокращениями.

**Дополнение** (к указанным предложениям)

Я бы оформила эти предложения так:
1.1. Напишите слово *лист* с префиксом *пол-* в **Р.** п.
1.2. Напишите слово *лист* с префиксом *пол-* в **р.** п.
2.2. Русские **тв.** и **им.** падежи — это нечто.

В первом примере, думаю, можно использовать оба варианта написания, так как речь идет о конкретном слове в конкретном падеже.

А вот во втором примере, считаю, лучше использовать строчные буквы — как обычное сокращение абстрактных слов (не совсем, правда, понятно чего ж такое "нечто" есть в именительном (начальном) падеже? Может, имеется в виду другой падеж?):
*Русские тв. и предл. падежи — это нечто.*

Из правил о числительных:

> Способность вступать в двойственные связи с именами существительными — управлять ими в им. и вин. падежах и согласовываться с ними в род., дат., тв. и предл. падежах.
>
> Способ связи с именем существительным — управление (существительное стоит в род. п. ед. или мн. числа)

Comment: В ответе надо разобрать все примеры и выбрать для каждой записи вариант сокращения. Эти варианты могут быть разными. Таким мне видится правильный ответ.  Там приходится выбирать нужный вид сокращения и прописную/строчную букву  в разных предложениях.

Comment: Да, *Sharon*, пожалуй, Вы правы — есть особенности. Я дополнила ответ.

Comment: Римма, а можно привести запись  четырех вариантов в том порядке, как это сделано у автора. Тогда ваше решение сразу будет ясным, а пояснения можно написать ниже.

Comment: Ну... Чего ж нельзя? Можно же ж...

Answer (score 1):

В начале предложения названия падежей, естественно, пишутся с большой буквы, в тексте - со строчной.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В ответе надо разобрать все примеры и выбрать для каждой записи вариант сокращения. Эти варианты могут быть разными. Предложите, пожалуйста, свое решение и запишите его полностью.

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнение к ответу @Римма Михайлова**

1. Напишите слово лист с префиксом пол- **в Р. п.**
2. Русские **тв. и им.** падежи — это нечто.

Я бы выбрала **только запись в Р. п.** Почему? Мне кажется важным обозначить **условность** обозначения падежей, выбрав только одну форму, причем с **прописной** буквы в середине предложения.

А во втором случае это уже не условное обозначение, а **обычное сокращение** слов в середине предложения (**строчная** буква).